# Does bitcoin deflate or does it appreciate?

Tags: terminology

How are these two terms related?

Bit Coin is obviously appreciating in value, but does that alone mean that the economy is deflationary? Or, is deflation and inflation a result of external pressures and not just the perceived value of the commodity?

Answer (score 2):

Since bitcoin is appreciating, the amount needed to buy the same stuff will be less in the future. That makes the economy around bitcoin deflationary.